# Проблема с типом money postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Как убрать  "р." для значений типа money?
выдает:

```
id | price    |
0  | 10,00 p. | 
1  | 12,00 p. |
```

а чтоб было вот так:

```
id | price    |
0  | 10,00    | 
1  | 12,00    |
```

---

и вопрос №2. Делаю резервную копию базы с помощью

> pg_dump.exe --host server.ddns.net
> --port 5432 --username "postgres" --no-password  --format custom --blobs --verbose --file "201503032012ii.backup" "LITVIN"

процесс возвращает 0, т.е. все ок.
позже восстанавливаю

> pg_restore.exe --host localhost --port
> 5432 --username "postgres" --dbname
> "develop_base" --no-password 
> --verbose "201503032012ii.backup"

Завершается с ошибками.
А именно:

```
pg_restore: [архиватор (БД)] сбой команды COPY для таблицы "AllItems":неверный синтаксис для типа money: "12,83 р."
```

локали и версии серверов идентичные, а восстановить не получается базу.

Answer (score 2):

*2-й вопрос*.

Скорее всего проблема в разных региональных настройках ОС на компьютерах.
Дополнительно проверьте параметр `lc_monetary` в обоих `postgresql` серверах.

Вот, что об этом сказано в официальной документации:

> Так как выводимые значения этого типа зависят от региональных настроек, попытка загрузить данные типа money в базу данных с другим параметром `lc_monetary` может быть неудачной. Во избежание подобных проблем, прежде чем восстанавливать копию в новую базу данных, убедитесь в том, что параметр `lc_monetary` в этой базе данных имеет то же значение, что и в исходной.